# Remove device admin

Tags: applications, adb, rooting, xiaomi, system-error

I am using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 10. My little brother tried to install Minecraft for free from google and now I have a device administrator app which cannot be uninstalled. When tried to remove admin privileges it says "Blocked by your IT admin"

I unsuccessfully tried removing admin privileges using ADB I tried to boot in safe mode, but it is just booting normally. I know I can boot in safe mode because I have done it before and saw the "Boot Mode" indicator, but now there is no indicator. I tried rooting the phone, but in developer settings the OEM unlocking option is also disabled by my admin so I don't know what to do now.

The app really slows my phone down. I can see that even though it's not opened it drained half my battery in one hour. I really need some serious help here. I will try everything you suggest.